# angular ui router places query string before hash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an application that uses an external payment provider to buy credits. After a successful purchase the payment provider redirects to `http://any.url/?orderNr=xxxx&outcome=SUCCESS`. This url is an AngularJS application that makes use of UI Router. The configuration of the router is this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
        isAuthenticated: true
    })
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl',
        isAuthenticated: false
        });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
```

So when the user comes back to the root of `http://any.url` and has already been logged in it redirects to the dashboard. This is the case after a payment because you cannot make payments without logging in. The problem is that the hashbang is placed after the query string, so the url of the dashboard becomes `http://any.url/?orderNr=xxxx&outcome=SUCCESS#/dashboard`. In the `DashboardCtrl` I'm unable to get the query string using `$location.search()`. Is there any way to get the query string the 'angular way', so not by parsing `location.href` ??

Comment: Can you control where the payment provider redirects? For example, tell the payment provider redirects to `http://any.url/#dashbard?orderNr=xxxx&outcome=SUCCESS`

Comment: @mmjmanders We're currently having this exact issue when using the spotify API to redirect back to the angular frontend, did you have any luck fixing it in the end?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the query string for the #/dashboard route, you should be able to specify parameters in the url config.

```
.state('dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard?orderNr&outcome',
```

Per the [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters)